# Using VLOOKUP by inputting cell numbers to search an entire column

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I want to make the VLOOKUP function dynamic by writing some VBA code to return the column number of the column the user is looking for and then doing a VLOOKUP on that column. This way, it doesn't matter where the user moves the column (just so long as the column header stays on row 1) as the application will automatically seek out the column number.

Writing a function to find a column on any given sheet was easy enough (only takes about 7 lines - open a question if you want it!) but the problem I have is once I have the column number and the row number (which is 2), I don't know how to put it into VLOOKUP.

Normally Vlookup on VBA would be using Range references. So a lookup on column M would be something like:

```
Application.VLookup(Datasheet.Cells(x, y), StaticSheet.Range("A:A"), 1, False)
```

But how do I get it to work for cell numbers? I tried

```
StaticSheet.Range(Cells(2,dataColumn):Cells(2,dataColumn))
```

in place of `"StaticSheet.Range(A:A)"`
but it doesn't work.

The easiest solution I can think of is to find the sheet's `usedrange` to get the last row, but is there an easier way?

Comment: @simoco I get a "Method 'Range' of Object '_worksheet' failed" error

Answer (score 2):

cells() returns a range object. The way you are using it here you want it to return an address.

```
Range(Cells(2,dataColumn):Cells(2,dataColumn))
```

Simply add `.address` and put your : in ""...

```
Range(Cells(2,dataColumn).address & ":" & Cells(2,dataColumn).address)
```

Comment: noticed an error: I meant to search the whole dataColumn, not just 2,(whatever column)

Comment: Why not just use `range(rows(datacolumn).address)` ?

Answer (score 2):

As dataColumn will always be the same when called on the same line twice you could modify your code as such

Change

```
StaticSheet.Range(Cells(2,dataColumn):Cells(2,dataColumn))
```

To

```
StaticSheet.Cells(2,dataColumn)
```

Comment: @SchwitJanwityanujit Can't explain why Added a picture to my answer to show this method works.

Comment: @user2140261, I think the problem is because you didn't specify sheet for cells. This should work: `StaticSheet.Range(StaticSheet.Cells(2,dataColumn),StaticSheet.Cells(2,dataColumn))`

Comment: @simoco I think you are right I wasn't even looking at that part of it, but I think the updated answer is even more simplfied

Comment: will check this at work tomorrow. however please don't feel offended if it works but I don't accept your answer; I feel for my fellow inexperienced, incapable compatriot who really don't have many opportunities to get SO rep anywhere unlike you who is obviously a VBA master! If only the experts on this site voted up newbie questions more often V_V

Comment: @simoco, TheAuthor: why is it that when I put 'StaticSheet.Cells(2,dataColumn)' it searches the whole column? Wouldn't it just search cell 2,(whatever column)? I probably should have been clear earlier: I want to search the ENTIRE column of dataColumn, not just location 2,(whatever column).